# Access to varBinds of received TRAP

Tags: python, pysnmp

I don't get how to access varBinds from code example. I can print it, but what if I want to store it or pass to method or class?

Even if I store it in class, I can't access it further.

```py
class TrapReceiver
    def __init__(self):
        # Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
        # to socket transport dispatcher
        self.snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()
        # Transport setup
        # UDP over IPv4, first listening interface/port
        config.addTransport(
            self.snmpEngine,
            udp.domainName + (1,),
            udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('127.0.0.1', 162))
        )
        # SNMPv1/2c setup
        # SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping
        config.addV1System(self.snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public')
    # Callback function for receiving notifications
    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal,PyUnusedLocal,PyUnusedLocal
    def cbFun(self,snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
                  varBinds, cbCtx):
            for varBind in varBinds:
                oid, value = varBind
                trap_source = str(oid)
                trap_val = int(value)
                #TODO: return trap_source, trap_val

    def run(self):
        # Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
        ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(self.snmpEngine, self.cbFun)

        self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)  # this job would never finish

        # Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send confirmations
        try:
            self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        except:
            self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
            raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "return" anything from a callback function. Because its caller (main loop) is not interested in its return value.

Therefore you should use `cbCtx` or some other global object (e.g. `dict`) to pass information received in the callback function to other parts of the application. The `cbCtx` object can be initially passed to `NotificationReceiver`, then it appears in the callback function.

So for example you can have notification receiver in one thread pushing received data into the `cbCtx` data structure (it can be `Queue` for instance), then another thread popping items from that `Queue` and processing them.

Or you can process received data right inside the callback function. Just make sure it's non-blocking.